# should not review audits be less confusing and tricky?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed another [closing review audit (Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926310/get-selected-option-to-php) today, anyway i find this one really a bad audit, its an accepted question with two answers, the issue is clear there, should not audits refer to clearly problematic posts, am i missing any issue on this one?

Comment: provide the review-audit link

Comment: @Azik http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2290822

Comment: yep, I think it's a bad audit, seems like audits needs some human supervising

Comment: Or, just stop using PHP questions as audits...